# Plotting average concentrations with depth in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics

I have data on calcium concentration taken at a range of depths, and I measured calcium in triplicate. I want to plot the average calcium concentration at each depth so that not every measurement is visible as a separate point. I can plot all the calcium concentrations separately so you can see every single calcium measurement(see code and plot) but can't seem to figure out how to plot just the average calcium concentration for each depth. Ultimately I need to be able add in the error bars for the stdev of Ca concentration as well, but that may be a problem for another time. Thanks for the help!

Plot of calcium concentration with depth, no averaging with depth

[image]

```
  Ca = ggplot(data = XRF, aes(x=Ca, y=depth)) +
      geom_point(aes(colour = Core)) +
      labs(title = "XRF Ca ppm with Depth at 1445A") +
      xlab("Ca (ppm)") +
      ylab("depth (mbsf)") +
      scale_y_reverse()
    Ca
```

Comment: Mmmm what about "Core"?  are "Core" and "depth" equal for each depth?
Better if you share a sample of data like dput(XRF)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming here that data is a dataframe. You can use `dplyr` to group by depth and then take the mean. Subsequently you can plot just one value per depth.

```
pacman::p_load(dplyr, ggplot2)
data(mtcars)

data <- mtcars %>%
    select(gear, mpg) %>%
    ungroup()

data %>%
    mutate(gear = factor(gear)) %>%
    group_by(gear) %>%
    summarise(mean = mean(mpg)) %>%
    ggplot() +
    geom_point(aes(x = gear, y = mean))
```

[image: example]

This would mean I think for you the following:

```
XRF <- data.frame(XRF) # in case you don't have a dataframe.
XRF %>%
    group_by(depth) %>%
    summarise(mean = (mean(Ca))) %>%
    ggplot() +
    geom_point(aes(y = depth, x = mean, colour = Core)) +
    labs(title = "XRF Ca ppm with Depth at 1445A") +
    xlab("Ca (ppm)") +
    ylab("depth (mbsf)") +
    scale_y_reverse()
```

NOTE: make sure you have dplyr installed.

For your second question, with the error bars, please take a look here: [Dot plot with mean point and error bars](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-error-bars-quick-start-guide-r-software-and-data-visualization). For some inspiration.

Comment: in case you want to treat the depth as categorical, use  `XRF <- mutate(depth = as.factor(depth))`

Comment: This is so helpful thank you! I already had dplyr installed so this fix was so quick and straight forward thank you! I'll check those other posts for my questions on error bars, tysm!!

Answer (score 0):

I have attempted to recreate your data to answer your question properly (see below). Let's first ensure it is similar to your own data set by using your own plotting code:

```r
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(data = XRF, aes(x=Ca, y=depth)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = Core)) +
  labs(title = "XRF Ca ppm with Depth at 1445A") +
  xlab("Ca (ppm)") +
  ylab("depth (mbsf)") +
  scale_y_reverse()
```

[image]

To get a mean at *every* depth, we can reverse the axes, use `stat_summary` and then flip the plot at the end. Note that summarizing at each depth means you can no longer indicate the core (unless the depths each came from a single core)

```r
XRF %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = depth, y = Ca)) +
  stat_summary(fun = "mean", geom = "point", aes(group = depth)) +
  labs(title = "XRF Ca ppm with Depth at 1445A") +
  ylab("Ca (ppm)") +
  xlab("depth (mbsf)") +
  scale_x_reverse() +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Of course, the problem here is that you still have a lot of points because there are a lot of unique depths. We can get round this by binning your data first:

```r
XRF %>%
  mutate(depth_breaks = cut(depth, seq(0, 60, 5), seq(2.5, 57.5, 5))) %>%
  mutate(depth = as.numeric(as.character(depth_breaks))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = depth, y = Ca)) +
  stat_summary(fun = "mean", geom = "point", aes(group = depth)) +
  labs(title = "XRF Ca ppm with Depth at 1445A") +
  ylab("Ca (ppm)") +
  xlab("depth (mbsf)") +
  scale_x_reverse() +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Doing it this way, we can get the standard errors even more easily:

```r
XRF %>%
  mutate(depth_breaks = cut(depth, seq(0, 60, 5), seq(2.5, 57.5, 5))) %>%
  mutate(depth = as.numeric(as.character(depth_breaks))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = depth, y = Ca)) +
  stat_summary(aes(group = depth)) +
  labs(title = "XRF Ca ppm with Depth at 1445A") +
  ylab("Ca (ppm)") +
  xlab("depth (mbsf)") +
  scale_x_reverse() +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Though perhaps to get an even better picture of the spread, we can use box plots:

```r
XRF %>%
  mutate(depth_breaks = cut(depth, seq(0, 60, 5), seq(2.5, 57.5, 5))) %>%
  mutate(depth = as.numeric(as.character(depth_breaks))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Ca, y = depth)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(group = depth)) +
  labs(title = "XRF Ca ppm with Depth at 1445A") +
  xlab("Ca (ppm)") +
  ylab("depth (mbsf)") +
  scale_y_reverse()
```

[image]

Or even with a regression showing the changing mean and interquartile range:

```r
library(qgam)

df <- data.frame(depth = seq(1, 60, 0.5),
                 upper = predict(qgam(Ca ~ s(depth), data = XRF, qu = 0.75),
                                 newdata = data.frame(depth = seq(1, 60, 0.5))),
                 lower = predict(qgam(Ca ~ s(depth), data = XRF, qu = 0.25),
                                 newdata = data.frame(depth = seq(1, 60, 0.5))),
                 Ca = predict(qgam(Ca ~ s(depth), data = XRF, qu = 0.5),
                              newdata = data.frame(depth = seq(1, 60, 0.5))))

df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = depth, y = Ca)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper), fill = "cornsilk",
              alpha = 0.3) +
  geom_line(linewidth = 1, linetype = 2) +
  geom_point(data = XRF, aes(fill = factor(Core)), shape = 21, size = 2.5) +
  labs(title = "XRF Ca ppm with Depth at 1445A, with median and IQR regression") +
  ylab("Ca (ppm)") +
  xlab("depth (mbsf)") +
  scale_fill_brewer("Core", palette = "Set1") +
  scale_x_reverse() +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16) +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = grid::linearGradient(
    c("#201008A0", "#80400840"), x1 = 0.5, x2 = 0.5)),
    panel.grid = element_line(color = "#00000040"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-07-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

**Data recreation**

```r
set.seed(6)

XRF <- data.frame(Ca = rgamma(70, 3, 0.8), 
                 depth = round(60 - runif(70, 0, 60))
                 )[-c(58, 52, 22, 3, 27, 59, 18, 13, 30, 6, 43,
                      64, 61, 5, 28, 45, 57, 67, 17, 56, 2, 8,
                      41, 44, 47),]
XRF$Ca[23] <- XRF$Ca[23] - 2
XRF <- XRF[rep(seq(nrow(XRF)), times = sample(1:4, nrow(XRF), TRUE)),]
XRF$Ca <- XRF$Ca + rnorm(nrow(XRF), 0, 0.1)
XRF$Core <- floor(XRF$depth/60 * 7)
```

Comment: Wow this was SO THOROUGH thank you so much!! You both answered my primary question, follow up about error bars, and then gave me so many more avenues for better visualization thank you! Catch me showing this post to my advisor too